# Delete rows from several tables in one query with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want delete rows of tables dispatch, scormvars and licencias but i am not sure if is it:
I have a select but i don't know to do the query with delete:

```
select
    distinct l.ID_plataforma as plataforma,
    s.ID_dispatch as dispatch,
    l.ID_licencia as licencia 
from scormvars s
left join dispatch d on s.ID_dispatch = d.ID_dispatch
left join licencias l on d.ID_licencia = l.ID_licencia
where l.ID_plataforma = 1483
```

Comment: I suggest looking into stored procedures or functions. You select the rows and your procedure will delete them as required. I would suggest to go toward this direction rather can combining queries.

Comment: i am not sure, i need delete 4 tables, in this select i have the id_plataforma to delete, id_dispatch to delete and id_licencia to delete. But i think is possible to do a query delete from... and delete all tables in  one query. How is the best solution ?, one procedure severals ?

Comment: You can do this from query as well. But creating a procedure, which grabs the data and then deletes it later would give you control over the deletion individually. With query you need to make sure the condition satisfies all joins or sub queries.

Comment: You are sure that a given `dispatch` does not appear in two different tuples from `scormvars`? At a first glance, it *looks* like you should be able to do this with a FOREIGN KEY CASCADE DELETE constraint...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write stored procedure to encapsulate all your steps, because it's not possible to delete rows from few tables in single query.

Also you can write AFTER DELETE trigger, and delete rows from one table when appropriate row deleted.

Moreover you can create foreign keys constraints...

But all this options are sophisticated...

As for me, i think more easiest way is use temporary table to store ids, and then delete appropriate rows using this temporary table. For example:

```
create temporary table idsToDelete
select
    distinct l.ID_plataforma as plataforma,
    s.ID_dispatch as dispatch,
    l.ID_licencia as licencia 
from scormvars s
left join dispatch d on s.ID_dispatch = d.ID_dispatch
left join licencias l on d.ID_licencia = l.ID_licencia
where l.ID_plataforma = 1483;
-- and then delete
delete from dispatch where ID_dispatch in (select dispatch from idsToDelete);
delete from licencias where ID_licencia in (select licencia from licencia);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would call the procedure when the database is not in use. It would be like this ?

```
create procedure prueba()
begin
        create temporary table idsToDelete
            select
            distinct l.ID_plataforma as plataforma,
            s.ID_dispatch as dispatch,
            l.ID_licencia as licencia 
            from scormvars s
            left join dispatch d on s.ID_dispatch = d.ID_dispatch
            left join licencias l on d.ID_licencia = l.ID_licencia
            where l.ID_plataforma in (select ID_plataforma from borrarplataformas);

            delete from dispatch where ID_dispatch in (select dispatch from idsToDelete);
            delete from licencias where ID_licencia in (select licencia from idsToDelete);
            delete from plataformas where id_plataforma in (select plataforma from idsToDelete);
            delete from scormvars where ID_dispatch in (select dispatch from idsToDelete);
end
```

Comment: How can i use cursors in this procedure ? for example, i would like to delete foreach 500 rows with commits.